# Search products with a specific attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, advanced-search

In my block code , I am trying programatically to search a list of products that have a attribute with a specific value. i am using this code for it.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');  
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('orig_price');    

//filter for products whose orig_price is greater than (gt) 100
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'orig_price','gt'=>'100'),
)); 

//AND filter for products whose orig_price is less than (lt) 130
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'orig_price','lt'=>'130'),
));
```

Comment: and what is the question here?

Comment: @Bay in magento ... i am using code on frontend/base/template/catalogsearch/advanced/result.phtml but its not working

Comment: @Marius i am adding attribute in advanced search page and i want to search with attribute value

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari did you checked [these links](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=IJwZWLrqIcSL8QfI6DY&gws_rd=ssl#q=magento+search+products+with+attribute+values)

Comment: @BabyinMagento .. yes i have checked this ...

Comment: anyone can help me in this regards i am waiting response.